# How to get the values in all rows of a particular ListView column?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `ListView` with three columns and I have added 4 records in the `ListView`.
I would like to get the value of the 2<sup>nd</sup> column value of each record. How to implement it?

Comment: It's probably more pragmatic to get the values from the underlying data source instead of from the display control.

Comment: if you are loading object values in listvew then see http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

Answer (score 5):

```
var vals = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(lvi => lvi.SubItems[1].Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Convert items to an IEnumerable for LINQ usage
ListViewItem[] items = new ListViewItem[4];
listView.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);

// Use LINQ to get values
IEnumerable<string> secondColumnValues = items.Select(_ => _.SubItems[1].Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

loop through all the  rows and try this.

Subitems[columnnumber] will be the column numbr of the required field

lv.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text

Comment: yeah i did like this but the loop is not executed. here is my code for(int i=0;i<=listview1.Items.Count;i++) { listview1.Items[i].Selected = true; string path = sch.m_playlist.SelectedItems[i].SubItems[1].Text; MessageBox.Show(path); }

Comment: Are you trying to do this? -

`for(int i=0;i<=listview1.Items.Count;i++)
 { 
 string path = listview1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text; 
 MessageBox.Show(path); 
 }`

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(ListViewItem itm in listView1.Items){ itm.Text/*first column of the particular item*/   itm.SubItem[1].Text/*second column of the particular item*/}
```

since foreach loop can access more fast than for loop